# access the same subdomain using another subdomain without changing url

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite

I have one host, but would like to show a different subdomain.  I have 2 subdomain's pointing to the one host.  The private subdomain called `private.thedomain.com` and the public called something like `the.public.domain.thedomain.com`.

What i'm looking to do is for people to use the `the.public.domain.thedomain.com` subdomain.  So if a user went to `the.public.domain.thedomain.com` it would go to `private.thedomain.com` without changing the URL to `private.thedomain.com`.

I have tried looking for the answer for a few days by searching and researching but nothing is pointing me to the right direction.  I have tried looking at mod_rewrite but it also does not seem to work for me, if someone could give me an example or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use the proxypass directive to use "private.thedomain.com" as a backend of "the.public.domain.thedomain.com"

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName private.thedomain
    DocumentRoot /var/www/private
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName the.public.domain.thedomain

    DocumentRoot /var/www/public

    Proxypass / http://private.thedomain
    ProxyPassReverse / http://private.thedomain

</VirtualHost>
```